# Cloud Build does not work anymore after upgrading to beam 2.30.0

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-build

i have been using this yaml file to kick off my dataflow flex workflow with beam 2.27.0, and it has always worked fine

```
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE
  entrypoint: python
  args:
  - /dataflow/template/main.py
  - --runner=DataflowRunner
  - --project=$PROJECT_ID
  - --region=$_REGION
  - --job_name=$_JOB_NAME
  - --temp_location=$_TEMP_LOCATION
  - --sdk_container_image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE
  - --disk_size_gb=50
  - --year=2018 
  - --quarter=QTR1 
  - --fmpkey=$_FMPKEY
  - --setup_file=/dataflow/template/setup.py
```

Today i decided to upgrade beam to 2.30.0, and when running exactly the same file i am now getting
this

```
Unrecognized SDK container image: gcr.io/datascience-projects/pipeline:latestRun. Custom container images are only supportedfor Dataflow Runner v2.
```

Could anyone advise what i need to fix? I am suspecting i'd need to run  using a cloud-sdk instead of python.....

kind regards
marco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `--experiment=use_runner_v2` as an argument, as the documentation is [covering](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers#usage), when working with Apache Beam 2.30.0 or higher versions.

Therefore your updated yaml will look like the following:

```
- name: gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE
  entrypoint: python
  args:
  - /dataflow/template/main.py
  - --runner=DataflowRunner
  - --project=$PROJECT_ID
  - --region=$_REGION
  - --job_name=$_JOB_NAME
  - --temp_location=$_TEMP_LOCATION
  - --sdk_container_image=gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_IMAGE
  - --disk_size_gb=50
  - --year=2018 
  - --quarter=QTR1 
  - --fmpkey=$_FMPKEY
  - --setup_file=/dataflow/template/setup.py
  - --experiment=use_runner_v2
```

Comment: brilliant! many thanks. must have missed that flag  regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you please have a look at the below checklist before you begin deploying and launching a python dataflow pipeline using cloud build.

- [Custom Containers](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers) support [Dataflow Runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2)
- The new Dataflow runner, Dataflow Runner v2, is now the default for
  Python streaming pipelines (version 2.21.0 or higher), and rolling
  out by default for Python Batch pipelines (version 2.21.0 or higher)
  starting February 2021.  You do not have to make any changes to your
  pipeline code to take advantage of this new architecture. Under
  certain circumstances, your pipeline might not use Runner V2,
  although the pipeline runs on a supported SDK version.
- You have to run the job with the **--experiments=use_runner_v2 flag**
- Dataflow Runner v2 requires the Apache Beam SDK version 2.21.0 or
  higher for Python, and version 2.30.0 or higher for Java. When
  running your pipeline, [make sure to launch the pipeline](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers?hl=en#before_you_begin_2) using
  the Apache Beam SDK with the same version (e.g. 2.XX.0) and language
  version (e.g. Python 3.X) as the SDK on your custom container image
- Custom containers must run the default ENTRYPOINT script /opt/apache/beam/boot, which initializes the worker environment and starts the SDK worker process. If you do not [set this entrypoint](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/using-custom-containers?hl=en#custom-entrypoint), your worker will hang and never properly start.

Note : Dataflow has stopped supporting pipelines using Python2. So be sure you are using python3 as runtime for the pipeline.